# Weird Eclipse / Java Bug: Instead of § there is a �

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

2 days ago I searched in the internet how I can change the Content Type of the Eclipse Editor to UTF-8, but since then my encoding is totally buggy.

Every §-Character changed to �, when I try to run the program it is still not working.

**An example:**

*What it should look like:*

> Bypass Mode: §eaus

*What it actually looks like*

> Bypass Mode: �eaus

Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check the encoding of your code file? on linux use `file MyClass.java`

Comment: try to write in any language that don't fall to Latin scripts like the Arabic or Chinese, then simply Ctrl-s to save the file, you will be prompted to change file encoding.

Comment: Is there a way I can undo this? I don't want to replace those � everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote files in some encoding before changing Eclipse settings to UTF-8, you need to change your files encoding as well (right click, Properties in Eclipse or use another tool depending on your platform).

Comment: Is there a way I can undo this? I don't want to replace those � everywhere.

Comment: Revert Eclipse setting to the encoding it was before (Cp1252 probably if on Windows).
But for future projects, use UTF-8 from the start ;)

Comment: Now there is a Â infront of the §, can I remove this too?

Comment: It means Cp1252 was not your encoding. Right click your file, Properties and check what is the encoding of the file. Set this encoding into Eclipse settings.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did but there still is a Â infront of the §

Comment: Ok, finally I fixed it.
Thank you very much! :)